# Drawing a configuration of topological lines and points

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

So I was wondering if there is a tool / similar to draw topological lines instead of straight lines on latex with points at their intersections? I was particularly looking to create this given image including the labels. [image]

Comment: To follow up with my comments on your other questions, here you only have to draw your lines (say with Bezier curves), name the paths, then find the intersections between the paths, using `intersections` library.

Comment: Would there exist an example of this somewhere?

Comment: Do you actually want intersections marked, or do you want over/under? What you've drawn almost looks like a braid diagram, and [there is a TikZ library for that](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/braids).

Comment: please feel free to edit & reopen if the linked set of answers does not help.

Comment: Have you done a search on braid with LaTeX?

Answer (score 2):

As for a starting point:

[image: paths intersections]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\tikzset{dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=red}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[name path=line1] (0,0) node[left] {line 1} .. controls ++(1,.5) and ++(-0.5,-2).. (3,0);
        \draw[name path=line2] (0,-1) node[left] {line 2} .. controls ++(1,-1) and ++(-1,1).. (3,1);
        \draw[name path=line3] (0,1) node[left] {line 3} .. controls ++(1,.5) and ++(-0.5,.5).. (3,-1);
        
        \path [name intersections={of=line1 and line2,by=A}];
        \path [name intersections={of=line1 and line3,by=B}];
        \path [name intersections={of=line2 and line3,by=C}];
        
        \foreach \p in {A,B,C}  \node[dot] at (\p) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [tikz-network](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-network?lang=en) package, which helps you drawing such paths using coordinates system, edges and vertices. (use `bend` for curves). Here is a simple example to start:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-network}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Vertex[x=0,y=0,NoLabel,color = black,size=.2]{a1}
\Vertex[x=0,y=2,NoLabel,color = black,size=.2]{a2}
\Vertex[x=3,y=1,NoLabel,color = black,size=.2]{c1}
\Vertex[x=6,y=0,NoLabel,color = black,size=.2]{b1}
\Vertex[x=6,y=2,NoLabel,color = black,size=.2]{b2}
\Edge[bend=-10](a1)(c1)
\Edge[bend=10](a2)(c1)
\Edge[bend=20](b1)(c1)
\Edge[bend=-20](b2)(c1)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. It would be useful to post a complete compilable code instead of a snippet, thanks. Not tom ention the fact that the question was about curves *and* intersections.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Your code does not compile. There is this error `Package xkeyval Error: "nolabel" undefined in families "vertex"`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, edited.